# What is the difference between UIViewController and UIInputViewController ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiinputviewcontroller

Here I'am working on **CustomKeyboardExtension**. In my extensible `.swift` class file the class definition starts with `UIInputViewController`

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

        // Add custom view sizing constraints here
    }
}
```

So what is the difference between `UIViewController` and `UIInputViewController`.

Answer (score 2):

`UIInputViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`. It has all the same functionality as `UIViewController` but also includes some extra logic. It is specifically designed for creating custom keyboards.

What all features are added into `UIInputViewController` is best seen in [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinputviewcontroller).